# How to get all the elements inside of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can only get the `input` tag but I also hope to get the `textarea` tag. How can I do that?

```
<div class="common-div">
    <input type="text" name="confirm-pwd"/>
    <textarea cols="150" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>

<script>
    $(".common-div input").each(function() {}):
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery has an [`:input` selector](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) which will grab all form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab all the elements in a container, there are many ways. For instance :

`$(".common-div *")` or `$(".common-div").find("*")` or `$(".common-div").children()`

Comment: Thank you very much,I'll give it a try

Answer (score 5):

You can enumerate them after comma:

```
$(".common-div input, .common-div textarea").each(function(){}):
```

Or, as @epascarello pointed out in a comment, use common class name for those elements you want to modify with jQuery.

Comment: Or use a common class on the elements you want to access.

Comment: complete example: `$(".common-div input, .common-div textarea").each(function() {});`

Comment: What if the form grows and counts 25 elements? Will you enumerate each one of them?

Comment: @JeremyThille - if there will be 25 kinds of elements (textarea, input and 23 others) - then maybe, but there will probably be like 5 textareas and 20 inputs, then I will not change anything

Comment: 非常感谢您的回答可能我也发现了方式    $(".common-div").children().each(function(){})

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div').children.click(function(){
//your code goes here..
});
```

may be this helps you out-

Comment: Yeah except `.children` is not a property of a jQuery object, it's a method. You need to call it : `.children()`

Comment: Thank you vary much,In the same way as I think

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the element inside a div by-

$(".common-div").find("*").each(function() {});

But it will return all other types of element in such as span, div, input, button Etc.

So if you want to get only input type where user can input text-

$(".common-div").find(":input").each(function() {});